# Encapsulating strings of variables in bash

Tags: bash

So I misrepresented my issue due to over simplification in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543298/how-do-i-pass-an-encapsulated-variable-into-a-new-environment/42543789#42543789).

Here is a better representation of the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

REALTEST+=" TESTVAR=\"some spaced string\""
REALTEST+=" TESTVAR2=\"some other spaced string\""

env -i $REALTEST /bin/bash -l -c "echo \$TESTVAR"
env -i '$REALTEST' /bin/bash -l -c "echo \$TESTVAR"
env -i "$REALTEST" /bin/bash -l -c "echo \$TESTVAR"
```

Here is the output:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./test1.sh
+ REALTEST+=' TESTVAR="some spaced string"'
+ REALTEST+=' TESTVAR2="some other spaced string"'
+ env -i 'TESTVAR="some' spaced 'string"' 'TESTVAR2="some' other spaced 'string"' /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
env: spaced: No such file or directory
+ env -i '$REALTEST' /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
env: $REALTEST: No such file or directory
+ env -i ' TESTVAR="some spaced string" TESTVAR2="some other spaced string"' /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
```

Any idea how I can get REALTEST to look like:

```
env -i TESTVAR="some spaced string" TESTVAR2="some other spaced string" /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
```

I can edit REALTEST but not the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case you can use arrays, you can define
the *REALTEST* variable as following.

```
REALTEST=('TESTVAR="some spaced string"' 'TESTVAR2="some other spaced string"')
```

The actual command then looks like

```
env -i "${REALTEST[@]}" /bin/bash -l -c "echo \$TESTVAR"
```

> I can edit REALTEST but not the echo.

If you do not want to write backslash before *$TESTVAR*, you can define it before hand like so.

```
TESTVAR="\$TESTVAR"
```

In the end the **Output** looks like this.

```
+ REALTEST=('TESTVAR="some spaced string"' 'TESTVAR2="some other spaced string"')
+ TESTVAR='$TESTVAR'
+ env -i 'TESTVAR="some spaced string"' 'TESTVAR2="some other spaced string"' /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
"some spaced string"
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I didn't even thing to use arrays!